# Fixing cURL error 35: error:14077410:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv3 alert handshake failure

Tags: php, ssl, curl, paypal, cpanel

I'm trying to connect to Paypal express checkout with a app, whenever a user registers, it throws a following error.

```
An unidentified error occurred.
cURL error 35: error:14077410:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv3 alert handshake failure
```

SSL is not required for Paypal express, but still I get this error. I have php v7. Please help me.

Comment: 1. SSL Is required for all API calls. Always has been. 2. It's trying to use SSLv3, which PayPal no longer supports [and neither should you](https://blog.qualys.com/ssllabs/2014/10/15/ssl-3-is-dead-killed-by-the-poodle-attack)

Comment: I'm using restrict content pro. There documentation says ssl is not required. If its trying to use SSL v3, is it the problem with the app or my hosting configuration should be changed?

Comment: You should see the solution in the duplicate first. Might fix your calls without any config changes

Comment: At the end of the answer in the Duplicate. You said it can be done by telling curl to use TLS. and you mentioned some code. $ch is my curl handler. One more question from a novice. how to find the curl handler?

Comment: Whatever you used `curl_init()` with